# protractor, how to pick the link inside an href

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tags, protractor, href

I'm new in protractor. I'm trying to take the href link inside an "a" tag but it never works. I tried in many ways with code that i found on web, but nothing of these worked with my project. I always get errors in this part of code.

Here's my html:

```html
<li class="main_navigation_field" role="presentation"><a href="https://www.google.com/" role="menuitem" class="main_navigation " data-linktext="primary Nav:Real Summary">Real Summary</a></li>
```

I tried with:

```
// var real_summary = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Real Summary")).getAttribute('href');         
// var real_summary = element(by.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Real Summary')]"));
// expect(real_summary).to.be.equal("https://www.google.com/");
        
// var real_summary = element(by.linkText('Real Summary'));
// expect(real_summary.getAttribute('href')).to.be.equal('https://www.google.com/');
var real_summary = element(by.partialLinkText('Real')).getAttribute('href');
        
// var real_summary = element(by.cssContainingText('.main_navigation','Real Summary')).getAttribute('href');
// var real_summary = element(by.cssContainingText("[href*=]","Real Summary")).getAttribute('href');
```

I get the following error (or similar errors)

```
"E/launcher - No element found using locator: By(partial link text, Booking)
[10:40:36] E/launcher - NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(partial link text, Booking)"
```

How can i do this correctly?

Comment: sounds like the error is pretty clear. It says that there's no link element with the text `Real` in it. check that the text is accurate. maybe it's lower case?

Anyway, if you'll include your HTML it might shine some light on the problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I taken the text "Real Summary" with drag and drop from my html page, so I don't expect that. Anyway I edited my question with my html code.

Comment: For the uncommented part, yes. This is true, but i can't used it. I need to delete it from my code. There are many links on the page that pointing the same Url, but i need to take the url inside href only for the tag that have "Real Summary" as displayed text.

Comment: I usually trust text selectors a lot less than standard CSS selectors. maybe try `element(by.css('[data-linktext="primary Nav:Real Summary"]')).getAttribute('href');` since it sounds like that attribute is unique for each link

Comment: I tried with your code, but is the same:
 E/launcher - No element found using locator: By(css selector, [data-linktext="primary Nav:Real Summary"])
[12:32:08] E/launcher - NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, [data-linktext="primary Nav:Real Summary"])

Comment: are you sure the page is loaded in the browser? if it is, can you open dev tools and select the element from there? The only other thing I can think of is that the page you expect to be loaded isn't loaded yet or not at all. Is the link element static, or is it injected into the HTML page (as in SPA)?

Comment: I'm working with AEM. 
The page I think is really loaded. The Drag and drop to take the correct text that i used, it was from the page on browser opened by my automated test launch. It works with template page, that have some components inside depending on which is the template page that I used. This is a text that on author our customer users edits on the dialog of the header component

Comment: Is the <li> element unique? You could potentially do something like `$('li.main_navigation_field a')` If that doesn't work, what are the specific parts of the html that are unique to that element?

Comment: @Spicchio, Your code is not match the error message.  Error message: 'By(partial link text, Booking)' said  can't find link by text 'Booking', not by `Real` described in your code.

Comment: Cause the Json has changed and i reported the error from the console without changing it. Anyway is the same field with another name. @BenMohorc I have many <li> in page, not only there